# Use Binding Context on Application Resources

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm

I have a Xamarin app which defines certain attributes and styles for the controls centrally in the **App.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="AppMsMovil.App">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Color x:Key="MainColorBlue">#003E62</Color>
        <Color x:Key="MainTextColorBlue">White</Color>
        <Color x:Key="SecondaryColorBlue">#6f95ab</Color>
        <Color x:Key="MainColorRed">#EC1B30</Color>
        <Color x:Key="MainTextColorRed">White</Color>
        <Color x:Key="SecondaryColorRed">#edb2b8</Color>
        <Color x:Key="MainColorGray">#e6e4df</Color>
        <Color x:Key="SelectedItemColor">#f7d6a1</Color>
        <Color x:Key="UnselectedItemColor">White</Color>

        <Color x:Key="CanceledColor">#ffa099</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ClosedColor">#fded98</Color>
        <Color x:Key="SentColor">#a9efbb</Color>

        <Style TargetType="Entry">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="PlaceholderColor" Value="Gray" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource MainColorBlue}" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="20" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource MainColorBlue}" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="DynamicOnDeviceLabelStyle" TargetType="Label" >
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding LcModel.DynamicOnDeviceLabelFontSize}" />
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="ContentPage" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource MainColorGray}" />
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="ContentView" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource MainColorGray}" />
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="Picker">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="TitleColor" Value="#7e8185"></Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="SearchBar">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="DarkGray"></Setter>
        </Style>

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

I'm trying to create a **Style** To apply the **FontSize** Property to **Labels** controles inside the application. However, i want the value of **FontSize** within the **Style** be determined deppending on the applicatrion execution environment. (If Tablet, i want a size, if cellphone i want another) To do this, i create the **Model** and **ViewModel** classes for the **App** class as follows.

Class: **AppModel.cs**

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace AppMsMovil.Models {
    public class AppModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private double LcDblDynamicOnDeviceLabelFontSize;
        public double DynamicOnDeviceLabelFontSize {
            get => LcDblDynamicOnDeviceLabelFontSize;
            set {
                if (LcDblDynamicOnDeviceLabelFontSize != value) {
                    LcDblDynamicOnDeviceLabelFontSize = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        /// Para actualizar los controles enlazados
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Class: **AppViewModel.cs**

```
using AppMsMovil.Models;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace AppMsMovil.ViewModels {
    public class AppViewModel {

        public AppModel LcModel { get; set; }

        public AppViewModel() {
            LcModel = new AppModel();
            SbSetDynamicOnDeviceProperties();
        }

        private void SbSetDynamicOnDeviceProperties() {
            string StrOnDeviceLabelFontSize = Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone ? "Small" : Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet ? "Medium" : "Medium";
            LcModel.DynamicOnDeviceLabelFontSize = (double)new FontSizeConverter().ConvertFromInvariantString(StrOnDeviceLabelFontSize);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, on the **App** class, i set the **BindingContext** with a **ViewModel** object.

Class: **App.xaml.cs**

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using AppMsMovil.ViewModels;

namespace AppMsMovil {
    public partial class App : Application {

        public bool IsLoggedIn {
            get {
                return Current.Properties.ContainsKey("IsLoggedIn") && (bool)Current.Properties["IsLoggedIn"];
            }
        }

        public App() {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new AppViewModel();
            MainPage = new AppShell();
        }

        protected override void OnStart() {
        }

        protected override void OnSleep() {
            Current.Properties.Remove("IsLoggedIn");
        }

        protected override void OnResume() {
        }            
    }
}
```

if i run the application, i can see that the **Model** and **ViewModel** class are created correctly, but, at i cannot see that the **Get** method of the **DynamicOnDeviceLabelFontSize** property on the **AppModel.cs** class is executed. so i think that the **Setter's** **Value** on my **Style** is not being assigned with that value.
(I confirm this because on the **XAML** file where im using the **Style**, is not taking the correct value)

NOTE: If i set a static value on **Setter's** **Value** of the **Style**, i can see that the **Label** control takes the correct value, so, this is not a **Style** problem, but it seems that the **Setter's Value** is not taking the value from **Binding**.

Question: Is it possible ti assign a value on a **Setter´s Value** of the **Style** in **Application.Resources** using a **Binding**? or i'm wrong with this??

Any support will be welcome.

Regards!

**UPDATE:**
Solved using ideas from comments... this is the final solution:

```
    <Style x:Key="DynamicOnDeviceLabelStyle" TargetType="Label" >
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{OnIdiom Phone=Small, Tablet=Medium}" />
    </Style>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried using [OnIdiom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.onidiom-1?view=xamarin-forms) to determine if it’s either a Phone or Tablet? Sorry I’m on a phone can’t post and answer with richer information.

Comment: You can use OnIdiom to determine which platform or which device is running on. It also has a class that you can use so you’re application stays MVVM.

Comment: Hi @ThisQRequiresASpecialist, thanks... i didnt try it... let me check out about this one... Thanks!!

Comment: Your question and code brings to mind a great vid by Xamarin guru James Montemagno called [Dynamic App Themes in Xamarin.Forms](https://youtu.be/4w8TQ8njd3w). Does this help answer your question?

Comment: @IVSoftware sounds good!... let me check it out!... Thanks!

Comment: @ThisQRequiresASpecialist, and IVSoftware... thanks guys!... with your ideas finally im solve this!... i'm gona update my post to describe the final solution found! Thanks!!

Comment: Considering posting an _answer_ to your own question instead! See [Can I answer my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: I have added a rich answer with a few other things I think you might find useful about styles on different devices, platforms and separations of style into their own section in the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally back at home, I want to show you some cool trick you can do with `OnIdiom`

1st: Using `OnIdiom` in `XAML`. You can use `OnIdiom` on any property of a Element in a view stack. This is useful to be able to manage different values depending on a device.

```
{OnIdiom Phone=Value, Tablet=Value}
```

2nd: There is also `OnPlatform` this enables you to do different things with different platforms.

```
{OnPlatform Android=Value, iOS=Value}
```

Further on you can combine these 2 to mix them together and this is how it looks combined

```
{OnIdiom Phone={OnPlatform Android=Value, iOS=Value}, Tablet={OnPlatform Android=Value, iOS=Value}}
```

You can go even a step further with styles and implement something along the line of this. You'll be able to determine if device is `General Size` or `Small Size`.

Inside `App.xaml` make sure to add `x:Name="dictionary` to your main `Application.Resources` otherwise you wont be able to load the custom `dictionaries` in the code behind.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Name="dictionary"> <----- IMPORTANT
    </ResourceDictionary>        
</Application.Resources>
```

Inside `App.xaml.cs` add this to the class. You want to determine what the screen size is, so we set couple of `const` of sizes. Create a method `IsASmallDevice` that will return `true` if device is small otherwise `false`.  We then want to load the styles with `LoadStyles` method by using `DeviceInfo` class and checking which platform we're working on to load correct styles. Once we have things understood we want to merge our custom `ResourceDictionary` with our `AppResource` `dictionary` by doing `MergedDictionaries.Add(our instance of ResourceDictionary)`.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    const int smallWightResolution = 768;
    const int smallHeightResolution = 1280;

    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadStyles();

        MainPage = new AppShell();
    }

    void LoadStyles()
    {
        var isSmall = IsASmallDevice();

        if (DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android)
        {
            if (isSmall)
                dictionary.MergedDictionaries.Add(AndroidSmallDeviceStyles.SharedInstance);
            else
                dictionary.MergedDictionaries.Add(AndroidDeviceStyles.SharedInstance);
        }else if (DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.iOS)
        {
            if (isSmall)
                dictionary.MergedDictionaries.Add(iOSSmallDeviceStyles.SharedInstance);
            else
                dictionary.MergedDictionaries.Add(iOSDeviceStyles.SharedInstance);
        }
    }

    public static bool IsASmallDevice()
    {
        var mainDisplayInfo = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;

        var width = mainDisplayInfo.Width;

        var height = mainDisplayInfo.Height;
        return (width <= smallWightResolution && height <= smallHeightResolution);
    }
}
```

Next you want to create `Content Page` and change it up like this. Make the `Content Page` into a `ResourceDictionary` allowing you to do the same as the `App` `ResourceDictionary` but seperated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                    x:Class="Class.Styles.AndroidDeviceStyles">

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Inside that `Content Page.xaml.cs` add this to enable it as `ResourceDictionry` and have a `static property` to make a new instance of that class allowing you to call it in the `App` depending on the device size that was loaded.

```
public partial class AndroidDeviceStyles : ResourceDictionary
{
    public static AndroidDeviceStyles SharedInstance { get; } = new AndroidDeviceStyles();
    public AndroidDeviceStyles()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Inside that new `ResourceDictionary` this is how you want to set new styles.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                    x:Class="Class.Styles.AndroidDeviceStyles">
    
    <Style x:Key="Public Key To Access Through Static Resource"
           TargetType="Your Targer Type e.g Grid">
        <Setter Property="WidthRequest"
                Value="100" />
        <Setter Property="HeightRequest"
                Value="100" />
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor"
                Value="Red" />
    </Style>
    
</ResourceDictionary>
```

This is how I usually do mine, one for each platform. I've found that it is almost impossible to get it right with a single style between each platform so yes I know it might be a lot of work to begin with but once it is done you'll be very happy with yourself having this kid of separation and control over each style in your application.
[image]

If you got any more questions about this please let me know in the comments I will be more than happy to show you more and explain things I might of forgot to mention in this answer.

Comment: Hello @ThisQRequieresASpecialist, this is very helpful!... Right now, im able to set properties depending on wich device the Application are running. I'm newer on Xamarin and MVVM architecture but, step by step, i'm creating a very nice application thanks to people like you.

Comment: You’re welcome @Gabo77. Happy coding. If you want MVVM examples for Xamarin or you’re stuck you’re more then welcome to post another question and I will give a rich explanation on it.

Answer (score 2):

Finally found a solution...

The model and viewmodel classes are not necessary, i only need to change this line.

Solved using ideas from comments... this is the final solution:

```
<Style x:Key="DynamicOnDeviceLabelStyle" TargetType="Label" >
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{OnIdiom Phone=Small, Tablet=Medium}" />
</Style>
```

Thanks a lot!